# How to protect my child from friend's over protective father?

Tags: parents, middle-childhood

My 9yo son has a class mate whose father doesn't allow her to socialize with boys.
The girl herself, on the other hand, is pretty adamant about being friends with my son, bordering on obsessive. I'd add that my son is a kind of person who considers all of his class mates friends, but I don't really see him as having any special inclinations towards this girl.

I had no clue what sort of situation at home she had until she started coaching my son how to avoid giving clues to her father that she's communicating with my son. For instance, she told him to change his picture on WhatsApp to some animal and she'll change his name to a girls name. Also, if they happen to be in the park at the same time, he should pretend he doesn't know her if her father is there as well, etc.

Later on, I've learnt that her father wouldn't let the girl go on a class day trip to the Opera because "that's no place for girls".

I understand there are cultural differences at play and I'm not in a position to judge another person's parenting. I just see her father's (imo) unhealthy attitude and her trying to get around him by lying as something that could blow up, and I wouldn't want my son anywhere near it when that happens.

I don't think telling my son to avoid the girl will really help, and I don't want him to cause him distress by changing his environment (class, school...). I also don't think there's anything school authorities can do in this case.

Is there any other way out of this situation?

**Edit**:
I should have explained that I (and the school staff) don't consider the girl to be abused. If anything, I think she usually gets whatever she wants, as long as it fits "what's for girls" (cultural/religious/what ever) stereotype, which I think has mainly to do with her social life. And this is exactly why I'm worried. If she was to get found out deceiving her father, there's a good chance she would spin it in a way that makes her the victim, and my son the instigator.

About the title change: I never meant to trigger people politically. English isn't my first language and where I'm from being "conservative" is more about general mindset than politics. Title corrected.

Regarding 9yo having a phone and WhatsApp: the phone we've given him is a dumb phone good only for calls and messages. There's no data plan, and it wouldn't be of much use even if there was. The phone was given to him so that he can go to and get back from school or park on his own and let us know if he wants to go to his frined's place, so basically so we can keep track of his whereabouts and so that he can reach us if he needs to. WhatsApp is installed on a tablet that is strictly for home use and he uses it for talking to his cousins and friends living abroad. We extended this to a few local friends during the time of strict social distancing regulations. The girl saw that he has a phone and asked him for his number. He asked us if it was ok to give the number to her, but at that time, we knew only that they seem to get along well.

Comment: Opera not being acceptable for girls is a new one

Comment: Even if things "blow up", what danger is **your son** in from the man?

Comment: _"... could blow up, and I wouldn't want my son anywhere near it when that happens."_ - Do you fear physical harm (to your son, or to the girl) if this blows up? Somewhat related: have you ever met the girl's father?

Comment: It may actually be it is the girl who needs help. Depending on where you live, the help may be available on government level. It may as well be the normal or at least acceptable behavior for a girl's father. It may also be the girl playing her own game.

Comment: @RonJohn Blame from the father for aiding and abetting (worst case : inciting her), and whatever consequences that follow. Her father doesn't seem to be a reasonable man in this subject - the consequences could be anything.

Comment: Writing not as a parent but as somebody who has witnessed indoctrination and this kind of borderline abuse before: I think there are relevant questions for the OP. (i) What culture is he in (USA/Europe, Israel etc.)? (ii) What is the culture of the "conservative" father? Personally, if this were Europe and the father were European I'd object strongly to his being described as "conservative", since European culture permits- in fact demands- controlled socialisation between children irrespective of gender, and somebody who denies that is not conserving Western values.

Comment: while not directly relevant, I would discourage my child from having their own picture publicly available on social media (i.e. a WhatsApp picture)

Comment: Could you add the country tag? In Germany it's possible to call special service which investigates child abuse.

Comment: @learner101 in situations like this, the girl gets blamed, not the boy.

Comment: It is possible this situation is not as it seems, and I don't see any answers addressing that. Is there a chance that these restrictions aren't actually coming from her father, but are part of a game for the girl? I know when I was 9, I had some friends with very active imaginations.

Comment: @AzorAhai I think the issue here is that the notion that something like opera not being suitable for girls is an **old** (read: outdated) idea, not a *new* one.

Comment: @fraxinus That's really a can of worms though, not something you want to set in motion unless you have very good reasons to do so.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think 9 is old enough to have a conversation about honesty and difference in cultures - the two things in play here.

Difference in culture angle :
Explain to your son what his friend's father views as acceptable and unacceptable behaviour, while making clear your position (that we don't subscribe to those ideologies, but we wont interfere nevertheless). Please take care not to paint their entire race/nationality/what-have-you this way. For all you know, its probably just the father's personal belief system.

Honesty angle :
If his friend feels stifled in these conditions, there are other ways to go about it than being dishonest and more importantly, make your son a party in the deception. I suspect this is where your concern lies mostly. Tell him so. Suggest to him (tell, may be? Definitely don't order) that he tell her he'll spend time with her, but wont change names or photos for it. Won't suddenly pretend he doesn't know her. May be he's already uncomfortable with all this? Ask him, if he is, your work just got a lot easier.

If he distances himself from the deception the girl has got going,

1. She will not want to take the risk of being caught and will stop hanging out with him
2. When it does blow up, he wont be anywhere near the wreckage

Comment: Have you thought about this from the girl's point of view?

Comment: While this is probably the safest option for OP son, i don't think it is morally as clear-cut. Honesty that enables cruelty is not morally justifiable, imho. On the other hand your son may have little chance to actually help her, and learning that is a harsh lesson for a 9yr old. (I have no answers myself)

Comment: @TonyK Yes, i have. While it breaks our hearts, I don't think OP is particularly looking for solutions on that front. She even accedes it to cultural differences. Edit : After looking at Graham's answer, I should admit that I didn't think the girl's problems could be at the level of actual abuse like being locked up without food.

Comment: @Ivana The cruelty is happening regardless of anything OP's son does.  Stopping the cruelty is an entirely separate problem, and deserves a separate solution (like reporting the girl's father to the relevant authorities, if it's really that bad.). There's no need for that solution to involve either of the children, indeed, it *shouldn't* involve them.  Deal with any larger legal / moral issues regarding the girl's father's behaviour as appropriate *after* OP's own son is clear of the fallout.

Comment: I dislike the situation, but friend's father has every _legal_ AND _moral_ right to control his child's friend groups. It certainly isn't fair to the little girl, but unless there is actionable evidence of abuse (i.e. call Child Welfare), you are extending yourselves _far, far_ beyond any perceived right to "help" or to correct another's (bad) parenting.

Comment: @Steve-O, I agree. It's just that i think this is not the right situation to illustrate the importance of honesty and cultural sensitivity to OP's son, more the contrary.

Comment: I agree with this answe mostly except the "honesty angle" part. It's important that a child not be made to feel guilty for being "dishonest" over lies or omissions to protect another person from an oppressive situation. Making children feel guilty over that is how you make snitches without empathy.

Comment: Specifically, OP asked "how to protect my child from..." and part of the impact of the likely-abusive father's actions is OP's child being put in a place of moral ambiguity over not cutting off or betraying his friend and feeling like he's being dishonest or otherwise "bad" if he doesn't. Sincere talks about what honesty means, when and why it's appropriate *and when it's not*, would go a long way towards helping the child avoid that, *even if he doesn't want to* be part of it.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Except my answer doesn't suggest making OP's son feeling guilty over being dishonest. I'm suggesting that the OP ask their son if he's feeling uncomfortable with the dishonesty that, frankly, was pushed upon him. It wasn't his own idea to protect her from oppression. If OP were to report that his son would also very much like to be in on that deception to protect her from her oppressor, both the question and the answers would have to be re-worded. But nothing of that sort in the question as it stands now.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE And I disagree with "even if he doesn't want to be part of it". I wouldn't push dishonesty on my child, even if it is to protect someone, if he doesn't want any part in it. This is a slippery slope, IMO.

Answer (score 52):

Can you talk to your son's friend?

Honestly, I think the belief that you can't judge another person's parenting is not true.  Certainly there are things where it doesn't much matter - table manners, for instance.  But at the other extreme, there is a point where physical or emotional abuse occurs and we *must* judge that.  And really it doesn't matter why.  Personal, religious or cultural reasons are immaterial.  As the analogy about consent goes, "Of course we can discuss why you're standing on my foot - but first you need to get off my foot."

My concern is that the father may actually have tipped over into the "abuse" scale.  Children with an abusive home life will naturally want to spend as much time away from home as they can.

If you can talk to the girl, then you may be able to find out a little of the background behind this.  You shouldn't sound judgemental, and you should be clear that you're not going to talk to her dad.  This is just so that your son can have a better time with her.

It's entirely possible that she's told a white lie about where she's going, and now she's stuck with the lie.  The whole thing could be entirely innocent.  Kids do that, and then they can start backfilling with not-very-credible continuing lies.  Naturally a parent becomes suspicious, and the whole thing snowballs, and often over something which isn't such a big deal in the first place.

But there's a chance she could be beaten and locked in her room without food routinely if her dad doesn't approve of who she's spent time with.  It happens.  And abusers are generally pretty careful to avoid letting their kids go round to other people's houses or away on field trips, because they might see how other people live and realise that what's happening to them is wrong.  On the off-chance that this might be the case, I don't think you want to push her away.

Comment: OP could be wrong, but from their question, it doesn't seem like its this extreme.

Comment: @learner101 I'd certainly hope not. But if the OP can talk to her, maybe they can make sure. It does seem very strange.

Comment: There is no good outcome to "hey, I think your parenting is a little overbearing, maybe we can set some good bounds to include my kid in your kid's friend group?" This isn't anything close to asking someone to step off _your_ foot -- it's kind of the other way around.

Comment: @Duthomhas That isn't anything close to what my answer says though.

Comment: Can you back any of these opinions with decent, reliable sources?

Comment: @learner101 : nah, other people raising their own kids according to their own beliefs, instead of indoctrinating them with **my** exact beliefs? That's child abuse!! People will upvote me for saying this!     *(by the way, that opera thing is indeed excessive... but calling that child abuse means living in a bubble and thinking everything else is broken except your exact way of life)*

Comment: @anongoodnurse For how kids can behave when they're caught in a lie, I'm going to cite my experience as a parent. :)  The only other thing I can think of which could be sourced is what happens to abused kids, and I am not going to post links to that.  I intended this to be more of a concern for the parent to check.  Since the OP has said in an edit that it isn't something they think is happening, I'm happy for this to start getting downvotes - I think it's voted way higher than it should be - but I think it stands as it is.

Comment: @vsz I wasn't calling that child abuse.  But a child who's not allowed on field trips, who wants to be away from her house as much as possible, who wants to cover up who she's been with because she's frightened of consequences - these are things which abused children do.  The OP says now that they don't think that's the case, and that's good, but it's valid to raise the concern.

Answer (score 16):

I would be concerned for your son. She can ask him not to say hello in the park as a favour but asking someone to stop being himself, and changing his picture on social media just for her benefit *does* sound obsessive and slightly worrying.

Your son has a right to be himself around everyone in his world and should not be encouraged to join in with someone else's subterfuge. That in itself will incriminate him in the father's eyes. Your son will be open to blame for aiding and abetting. I have no idea of the culture involved but things can become dramatic for some cultures. Brothers can be very protective of sisters.

To have a healthy life the girl needs to have many friends at that age including other girls. She may have a crush on your son and be trying to isolate him from others by "telling" him how to behave.

If you or any other adult has concerns about the girl's welfare then that is a concern for adults only. Other children should not be involved at any level - they don't have the maturity to deal with it.

Concerned? Speak to the teachers, headteacher,  school counselor, or anyone who is responsible for pupils' welfare. State the bald facts without attributing blame to the girl or to her father. Don't mention culture at all.

Comment: My answer was on similar lines, but what you said "If you or any other adult has concerns about the girl's welfare then that is a concern for adults only." -- This drives home the point! +1.

Comment: Completely disagree with this answer. She's not asking OP's son to do anything wrong. This situation is an opportunity for an important lesson that lying is *not* unconditionally wrong and that sometimes it's a necessary way people protect themselves from oppressive sitations.

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE - Sometimes lies lead to unpleasant situations depending on who you are dealing with. To go against another parent's wishes, especially a very strict parent, could cause big trouble for just about everyone if that parent ever finds out.

Answer (score 6):

That may sound really weird but if i were you i'd concern more about the girl.

If she is talking to your son and ask him effort to keep seeing him that's because he may be his only friend and possibly a light for her. Bad treatment occurs probably and he may be the most important emotional support for her. Yeah your kiddo may be her hero.

And if the two kids are linked then he would be really mad if anything you say or you does take her away from him cause in those ages feelings aren't as rational as adult's one.

In my opinion you should discuss him about her and try to know more trough him. If you are enough interested he may reveal you what she tells him and maybe find that she is victim of bad treatment.

Your main role is to care about your son but once he cares about someone you should give a little attention to this person and if it necessary try to help the person.

Just a point of view of course but that's the kind of education that may helps many boys and girls in the world.

Answer (score 5):

I think the other answers cover it, but here is another angle.

Children (although teens more than anything else) pretty much always do *something* their parents strongly disapprove of them doing, be it drugs or sex or piercings or violent video games or skateboarding.

Then they introduce their friends to it and teach them how to deceive their parents, although in some cases (such as this one) those parents are OK with the activity.

And what happens when the strictest parents find out? They usually ban their child from associating with the others, and if it goes on, they institute more and more preventative or punitive measures against their child. I strongly suspect that is what will happen here, although you never know. Fathers can get particularly furious at boys who are having something resembling intimate relations with their daughter.

Your son may feel he is being "kind" to the girl by doing what she asks—and truth be told his company may be her only outlet for some sort of duress—but on the other hand he's an accessory to a big risk she's taking in both defying *and* deceiving her father. But it can be very hard to say "no" and hard to know *how* to say "no." Perhaps something along the lines of "I'm sorry but I don't feel it's right to do it if your father doesn't want you to."